# keeping radio button in jquery by removing button tag and change color by when click on button

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, radio-button

I want to get radio buttons instead of buttons

```
function getunits(val)
  {
    var formdata = new Object();
    formdata.unit_id = val;
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: site_url + "welcome/unitlist",
      data:formdata,
      success: function(data){
        var res=JSON.parse(data);
        var html='';
        var html2='';
        var html3='';
        for(var i=0; i<res.data.length ; i++){
          html += "<button class='col-xs-6 btn btn-primary'>"+res.data[i].prop_unit_num+"</button></br></br>";
          if(res.data[i].prop_unit_status =="sl")
                {
                  html3 += "<button class='btn btn-success'>sale</button></br></br>"
                }else if(res.data[i].prop_unit_status =="sol")
                {
                  html3 += "<button class='btn btn-danger'>sold</button></br></br>"
                }else{
                  html3 += "<button class='btn btn-info'> No status </button></br>"
                }
          html2 += "<select id='statusid"+i+"' onchange='clickokbutton(this.value,"+res.data[i].prop_unit_id+")'>";
          html2 +="<option value =''>select option</option>"
           for(var j=0; j<res.dropdown.length ;j++){
                html2 += "<option value='"+res.dropdown[j].prop_unit_status_id+"'>"+res.dropdown[j].prop_unit_status_desc+"</option>";

              }
          html2 += "</select></br></br>";
           if(res.data[i].prop_unit_status){
            //$('#statusid"+i+" option:selected').val();
            //$("#statusid"+i+"").val(res.dropdown[j].prop_unit_status_id.res.data[i].prop_unit_status);
        }
          $('#status').html(html2);
        }
        $('#units').html(html);
        $('#statusdesc').html(html3);
      }

    });
  }
```